# Groovy way to check if a list is sorted or not

Tags: list, sorting, groovy

Does Groovy have a smart way to check if a list is sorted? Precondition is that Groovy actually knows how to sort the objects, e.g. a list of strings.

The way I do right now (with just some test values for this example) is to copy the list to a new list, then sort it and check that they are equal. Something like:

```
def possiblySorted = ["1", "2", "3"]
def sortedCopy = new ArrayList<>(possiblySorted)
sortedCopy.sort()
```

I use this in unit tests in several places so it would be nice with something like:

```
def possiblySorted = ["1", "2", "3"]
possiblySorted.isSorted()
```

Is there a good way like this to check if a list is sorted in Groovy, or which is the preffered way? I would almost expect Groovy to have something like this, since it is so smart with collections and iteration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not just compare it to a sorted instance of the same list?

```
def possiblySorted = [ 4, 2, 1 ]

// Should fail
assert possiblySorted == possiblySorted.sort( false )
```

We pass `false` to the sort method, so it returns a new list rather than modifying the existing one

You could add a method like so:

```
List.metaClass.isSorted = { -> delegate == delegate.sort( false ) }
```

Then, you can do:

```
assert  [ 1, 2, 3 ].isSorted()
assert ![ 1, 3, 2 ].isSorted()
```

Comment: And just to be sure: There is no other shorthand built-in in the Groovy language for this check?

Comment: @MagnusTengdahl No, not that I know of :-( You can add one to the metaClass of List (or Collection) though (I posted how above in my answer)

Answer (score 13):

If you want to avoid doing an O(n*log(n)) operation to check if a list is sorted, you can iterate it just once and check if every item is less or equals than the next one:

```
def isSorted(list) {
    list.size() < 2 || (1..<list.size()).every { list[it - 1] <= list[it] }
}

assert  isSorted([])
assert  isSorted([1])
assert  isSorted([1, 2, 2, 3])
assert !isSorted([1, 2, 3, 2])
```

Comment: +1 Good call (though with Java 7 I believe `n*log(n)` is the worst case as java has swapped to use the brilliantly named [timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort)).  You could also make your code fail fast by using: `boolean isSorted(list) { list.size() < 2 || !(1..<list.size()).find { list[it - 1] > list[it] } }`

Comment: Or it's probably less obtuse to use every like so: `boolean isSorted(list) { list.size() < 2 || (1..<list.size()).every { list[it - 1] <= list[it] } }`

Comment: Didn't know about the Timsort, Tim =P; thanks for the link! -- About the second message, isn't it exactly the same solution (apart from the return type declaration)?

Comment: LOL!  Yes.... I thought you had `each`.  I apologise profusely (and should have known better) :-(

Comment: No problem; i just had to do char-by-char diff with my eyes to be sure =P